# Maven GAE Plugin using Google Cloud SQL

Tags: sql, google-app-engine, maven, cloud, maven-plugin

Good morning,

I am trying to local test my web application, which makes use of:

- Spring (core + MVC)
- Google AppEngine
- Google Cloud SQL
- Hibernate

In this page https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/developers_guide_java Google explains how to make the hello world run, and that's right.
I deploy to AppEngine with no problems.

The next need is testing on the local system, with a local standard mysql instance and that document goes ahead in the explanation. You can give your local access credentials by command-line or by Google Eclipse Plugin.

But I am using the Maven GAE Plugin http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/ and simple `mvn gae:run` ends up with this error:

```
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mySessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: System property rdbms.driver must be set.:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: System property rdbms.driver must be set.
    at com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.dev.LocalRdbmsServiceLocalDriver.registerDriver(LocalRdbmsServiceLocalDriver.java:80)
```

That's a pretty descriptive error, so I desperately tried:

```
mvn gae:run -Drdbms.server=local -Drdbms.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -Drdbms.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prova?user=root&password=pass
```

... with no result! :-(

Help!  O.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using plugin's **jvmFlags**

Comment: How do you use this Fabio? Thanks!